# Example of Propensitiy Score Matching (PSM) in Dif-in-Dif (DiD) using R?

Tags: r

I'm working with impact analysis and my data is in the form of a dashboard. My data set is from the years 2010 to 2016 and my treatment group are graduate students who received a scholarship. My control group are graduate students who did not receive a scholarship, in addition, my result variable is the student salary. I am adjusting a model differences in differences.
Dif-in-Dif (DiD), combined with Propensitiy Score Matching (PSM), how can I adjust in R? So far I've found codes, but only with PSM, DID can't find them. Can anybody help me?

my data are in the image below, my treatment variable is "TRAT", my result variable is "INCOME" and the others are the observable variables to perform the pairing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRAtp.png)

Comment: mpact-analysis propensity-score-matching

Comment: Please read how to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Can you show an example of your data (with `dput`). What have you done so far? Where are you stuck?